# How to display the user's profile picture in an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I recently started Android development. And whenever I send a message to somebody within the messaging app, **the listview item that displays has my avatar or display picture on it.**

***How can I do this within my app too?*** Can I fetch it somehow programmatically, and then set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the user doesn't have a "display picture" as default, and as far as I am concerned there is no way of finding the user's Gmail account information through Android, as there is for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the name of that corresponding picture while parsing the data and using that name,u need to fetch it from server where this picture is store.That is using the path+the picture name.now u will have the picture in the form of a bitmap.Now the only thing you have to do is to assign this bitmap to an imageview.Now its complete.You can see that image in the imageview

Comment: Wait, what? How do I get the name of the picture?

Comment: You will have this image name stored in the database of the server from were u are fetching ur profile pic.for example,say you need to fetch the pic from ur facebook.You can acess the facebook server(you first need to integreate fb first),and get the picture name.Or if you hav your picture in some database of a server,you need to parse data from that server using json or some other parsing mechanism based on ur data.then you will be able to get the picture name

Comment: So there is no profile picture stored on the phone itself, like there is on Windows Phone?